# Making a array on click and toggle its class through angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a application regarding scheduling e.g I have 2 enrolled person with 11 dates.

When user clicks on month it should get added in the array and it should get highlighted. For the 2nd time it should get removed from array without highlighting and only new date should get added.

Comment: [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fRJHyPve8fNoi2u3KUg9?p=preview)

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is what you inteded, check it out: [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/FHoRJgx81MOSTZL9giKy?p=preview)

In short, it is better to pass entire object reference and operate with it rather then only date:

```
ng-click="addToCart(schedule);"
```

and key is to cache array index:

```
var index = $scope.myCartItems.indexOf(item.EMIDate);
```

Comment: it solved half of my problem TY..... one more thing I need is that selection should be in sequence...